# Replacing XML tags in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML document with an `<en-media>` tag:

```
<en-media type="image/png" hash="06c5ec15535babbcd3eef471f51af870"/>
```

I am trying to change that tag to a HTML `<img>` so it would look like the following:

```
<img src="06c5ec15535babbcd3eef471f51af870"/>
```

This works as the file is named after its hash.

I have been using xml.etree.ElementTree to try to do this and I have been looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html but I cant seem to get anything near working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done with ElementTree.

Input XML (test.xml):

```
<root>
  <en-media type="image/png" hash="06c5ec15535babbcd3eef471f51af870"/>
</root>
```

Python code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("test.xml").getroot()

# Get the 'en_media' element
en_media = root.find("en-media")

# Add the 'img' element (with 'src' attribute) as a sub-element of 'root'
img = ET.SubElement(root, "img", src=en_media.get("hash"))

# Remove 'en_media'
root.remove(en_media)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <img src="06c5ec15535babbcd3eef471f51af870" /></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BeautifulSoup**.

for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = BeautifulSoup("<somelink rel='stylesheet'>")
print a
# output : <html><body><somelink rel="stylesheet"></somelink></body></html>
b = a.somelink
b.name = "link"
print a
# output : <html><body><link rel="stylesheet"></link></body></html>
print b
# output : <link rel="stylesheet"></link>
```